# c++ Range_Based Loop with custom Object

Tags: c++, object, foreach

i have two objects that look like this:

```
class Object
{
};

class List
{
public:
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Object>> list;
};
```

and i want to be able to create a range-based Loop like this:

```
for (Object& object : list) {
    //...
}
```

for that i created the begin() and end() members:

```
class List
{
public:

    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Object>> list;

    Object& begin() { return *list.begin()->get(); }
    const Object& begin() const { return *list.begin()->get(); }
    Object& end() { return *list.end()->get(); }
    const Object& end() const { return *list.end()->get(); }
};
```

but the IDE is now asking me for the operators *, ++ and != and i dont undestand how i am supossed to implement can i get some help with that?

Comment: You have not provided meaningful `begin` and `end`. They should return iterators, not objects. Also, dereferencing `end` iterator is UB, but you won't need that piece of code.

Comment: @LogicStuff then how do i convert the shared_ptr to a reference?

Comment: @Dolfos You will need to write an iterator type for `List`. Trying to convert your `shared_ptr`s to references instead of using an iterator type would be a mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The range-for protocol requires that `begin()` and `end()` return a type that conforms to the standard library's [Iterator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Iterator) concept. This includes things like being able to dereference the iterator with `operator*`, and increment it with `operator++`.

An object reference, as you are returning from your `begin(),` does not meet these requirements, which is what the compiler is complaining about.

Writing your own iterator is quite tedious, especially if you want to support all the random-access facilities that `std::vector`'s iterators offer. There are libraries that can make this a bit easier though.

A far more straightforward way to do things would be to simply forward the iterators that your `list` member already gives, i.e.

```
class List
{
public:
    using iterator = std::vector<shared_ptr<Object>>::iterator;
    using const_iterator = std::vector<shared_ptr<Object>>::const_iterator;

    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Object>> list;

    iterator begin() { return list.begin(); }
    const_iterator begin() const { return list.begin(); }
    iterator end() { return list.end(); }
    const_iterator end() const { return list.end(); }
};
```

Now you can use a `List` in a range-for loop by saying

```
for (auto& optr : list) {
    do_something_with_object(*optr);
}
```

The only catch is that dereferencing the iterator will give you a reference to a `shared_ptr<Object>`, not an `Object&`, so you'll need to dereference this again to actually use the object itself (as above).

Answer (score 1):

Range-based for loops need more than some arbitrary objects to be returned by `begin()` and `end()`.

```
for (auto& object : list) { ... }
```

for your list is [per definition](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) more or less equivalent to the following:

```
{
    auto iterator = list.begin();
    auto end = list.end();
    for ( ; iterator != end; ++iterator)
    {
        auto& object = *iterator;
        ...
    }
}
```

That is why your compiler asks you for all these operations (`!=`, `++`, `*`), as it tries to apply them to the object returned by `begin()`.

The problem is that you are expected to provide an [iterator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Iterator), not just the first and last element of your list. You cannot give the compiler two different `Object`s and expect it to be able to loop through a list of pointers to them (which is not necessarily visible from the loop).

Tristan provided you with some options in his answer. I would add that the [ranges library](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3) can remove a lot of the tedium from writing your own iterators, but it is most likely overkill for your situation and probably not the easiest to get accustomed with.

Answer (score 0):

If you grasped previous replies, I rewrite them in a short snippet. No need for any typedef:

```
class List {
public:
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Object>> list;
    auto begin() { return list.begin(); }
    auto begin() const { return list.begin(); }
    auto end() { return list.end(); }
    auto end() const { return list.end(); } 
};
```